# Create failed for Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I opened my SSMS with Run as Administrator. I connected to the instance as shown below using Window Authentication.

[image]

I tried to create a new login and everytime it is showing below mentioned error....

[image]

Comment: Is this database on your local machine?

Comment: I think the user you logged into SSMS with doesn't have permissions to create a user.  Can you check that?

Comment: @SachinKainth - it's at my Laptop.

Comment: ok check the user permissions.

Comment: @SachinKainth I logged in with Window Authentication

Comment: ok then in SSMS can you check that the user you logged into windows with has permissions to create users.

Comment: @SachinKainth How can I check that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11329/discussion-between-nilish-and-sachin-kainth)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the security tab of your database and check that the user you logged into SSMS with appears in the Users tab.  If not add him and then ensure he has all the right permissions.  Or log on to SMSS with the sa account.

Answer (score 1):

your "Run as Administrator" means as a windows administrator.

To be able to create a database you need to log into SQL Server using a login that has create database permissions

right click your login and make it a dbcreator:

[image]

Comment: create your own login with ad\your_AD_ID. It will do the AD mapping automatically

Comment: While creating new login it says you don't have permission.

Comment: can you decrypt the password here is the script `CREATE LOGIN [sa] WITH PASSWORD=N'ôö¡Áõßv_´ë=7^D''ö§TÝ¶ê
@Í°É gf', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=ON
GO`

Answer (score 0):

-close your application
-right click on mouse and run as administrator

its happen to me

Comment: This didn't make any difference for me